# не собирается простейший пример движка amethyst-0.15.1

Tags: rust, amethyst

не собирается простейший пример движка amethyst-0.15.1

```
C:\Dima\Rust>cd amethyst-0.15.1

C:\Dima\Rust\amethyst-0.15.1>cargo run --example hello_world
    Updating crates.io index
  Downloaded semver-parser v0.7.0
  Downloaded mint v0.5.9
  Downloaded is-terminal v0.4.10
  Downloaded edit-distance v2.1.0
  Downloaded cfg-if v0.1.10
  Downloaded gltf-derive v0.15.2
  Downloaded unic-langid-macros v0.8.0
  Downloaded atty v0.2.14
  Downloaded phf_codegen v0.7.24
  Downloaded derive-new v0.5.9
  Downloaded inventory-impl v0.1.11
  Downloaded phf v0.7.24
  Downloaded build_const v0.2.2
  Downloaded raw-window-handle v0.3.4
  Downloaded rental v0.5.6
  Downloaded rendy-memory v0.4.1
  Downloaded rendy-factory v0.4.1
  Downloaded jpeg-decoder v0.1.22
  Downloaded phf_shared v0.7.24
  Downloaded intl_pluralrules v6.0.0
  Downloaded autocfg v0.1.8
  Downloaded rendy-frame v0.4.1
  Downloaded proc-macro-crate v0.1.5
  Downloaded cty v0.2.2
  Downloaded rand_xorshift v0.1.1
  Downloaded specs-hierarchy v0.6.0
  Downloaded rand_pcg v0.2.1
  Downloaded quote v0.6.13
  Downloaded dirs v2.0.2
  Downloaded crc v1.8.1
  Downloaded shrev v1.1.3
  Downloaded rand_chacha v0.2.2
  Downloaded rendy-command v0.4.1
  Downloaded time v0.1.45
  Downloaded getrandom v0.1.16
  Downloaded png v0.15.3
  Downloaded rand_distr v0.2.2
  Downloaded syn v0.14.9
  Downloaded syn v0.15.44
  Downloaded tuple_utils v0.3.0
  Downloaded rendy-descriptor v0.4.1
  Downloaded unic-langid-macros-impl v0.8.0
  Downloaded fern v0.6.2
  Downloaded rustc_version_runtime v0.1.5
  Downloaded lexical v2.2.4
  Downloaded ron v0.5.1
  Downloaded rendy v0.4.1
  Downloaded font-kit v0.5.0
  Downloaded objekt v0.1.2
  Downloaded lzw v0.10.0
  Downloaded rendy-util v0.4.1
  Downloaded palette v0.4.1
  Downloaded fluent-syntax v0.9.3
  Downloaded nalgebra v0.19.0
  Downloaded lexical-core v0.4.8
  Downloaded xi-unicode v0.2.1
  Downloaded winit v0.19.5
  Downloaded rendy-graph v0.4.1
  Downloaded relevant v0.4.2
  Downloaded rendy-mesh v0.4.1
  Downloaded tiff v0.2.2
  Downloaded thread_profiler v0.3.0
  Downloaded rendy-texture v0.4.1
  Downloaded shred-derive v0.6.3
  Downloaded rendy-shader v0.4.1
  Downloaded rental-impl v0.5.5
  Downloaded rendy-wsi v0.4.1
  Downloaded fluent-langneg v0.12.1
  Downloaded proc_macro_roids v0.7.0
  Downloaded glyph_brush v0.6.3
  Downloaded wavefront_obj v6.0.0
  Downloaded dwrote v0.9.0
  Downloaded rand v0.6.5
  Downloaded specs v0.16.1
  Downloaded image v0.21.3
  Downloaded cpal v0.11.0
  Downloaded crossbeam-channel v0.4.4
  Downloaded shred v0.10.2
  Downloaded png v0.16.8
  Downloaded minimal-lexical v0.2.1
  Downloaded gltf v0.15.2
  Downloaded base64 v0.11.0
  Downloaded lyon_geom v0.14.1
  Downloaded hashbrown v0.7.2
  Downloaded palette_derive v0.4.1
  Downloaded type-map v0.3.0
  Downloaded png v0.14.1
  Downloaded toml v0.5.11
  Downloaded rustc_version v0.4.0
  Downloaded laminar v0.3.2
  Downloaded failure v0.1.8
  Downloaded slice-deque v0.3.0
  Downloaded intl-memoizer v0.4.0
  Downloaded getset v0.0.9
  Downloaded arrayvec v0.5.2
  Downloaded glsl-layout-derive v0.3.2
  Downloaded fluent v0.11.0
  Downloaded glsl-layout v0.3.2
  Downloaded tiff v0.3.1
  Downloaded rand_core v0.3.1
  Downloaded synstructure v0.12.6
  Downloaded maybe-uninit v2.0.0
  Downloaded proc-macro-error v1.0.4
  Downloaded quickcheck v0.9.2
  Downloaded env_logger v0.7.1
  Downloaded lyon_path v0.14.0
  Downloaded alga_derive v0.9.2
  Downloaded rendy-resource v0.4.1
  Downloaded hibitset v0.6.4
  Downloaded raw-window-handle v0.4.3
  Downloaded rand_jitter v0.1.4
  Downloaded rendy-chain v0.4.1
  Downloaded tinystr v0.3.4
  Downloaded rand_core v0.5.1
  Downloaded rand_hc v0.1.0
  Downloaded approx v0.1.1
  Downloaded rand_pcg v0.1.2
  Downloaded proc-macro-hack v0.5.20+deprecated
  Downloaded rodio v0.11.0
  Downloaded static_assertions v0.3.4
  Downloaded num-derive v0.2.5
  Downloaded quick-error v1.2.3
  Downloaded paste v0.1.18
  Downloaded serde_bytes v0.11.14
  Downloaded semver v1.0.21
  Downloaded stb_truetype v0.3.1
  Downloaded smallvec v0.6.14
  Downloaded siphasher v0.2.3
  Downloaded rand_os v0.1.3
  Downloaded rand_isaac v0.1.1
  Downloaded memoffset v0.5.6
  Downloaded crossbeam-queue v0.2.3
  Downloaded rustc_version v0.2.3
  Downloaded image v0.22.5
  Downloaded chrono v0.4.33
  Downloaded image v0.23.14
  Downloaded miniz_oxide v0.3.7
  Downloaded phf_generator v0.7.24
  Downloaded specs-derive v0.4.1
  Downloaded rand v0.7.3
  Downloaded claxon v0.4.3
  Downloaded num-bigint v0.4.4
  Downloaded nom v7.1.3
  Downloaded euclid v0.20.14
  Downloaded deflate v0.7.20
  Downloaded unicode-normalization v0.1.22
  Downloaded cgmath v0.16.1
  Downloaded semver v0.9.0
  Downloaded minimp3-sys v0.3.2
  Downloaded itertools v0.8.2
  Downloaded minimp3 v0.3.5
  Downloaded parking_lot_core v0.6.3
  Downloaded arrayvec v0.4.12
  Downloaded bytes v0.5.6
  Downloaded gfx-hal v0.3.1
  Downloaded derivative v2.2.0
  Downloaded deflate v0.8.6
  Downloaded rand_core v0.4.2
  Downloaded parking_lot_core v0.7.3
  Downloaded alga v0.9.3
  Downloaded colorful v0.2.2
  Downloaded proc-macro2 v0.4.30
  Downloaded colored v1.9.4
  Downloaded base64 v0.10.1
  Downloaded num-rational v0.3.2
  Downloaded parking_lot v0.10.2
  Downloaded crossbeam-epoch v0.8.2
  Downloaded parking_lot v0.9.0
  Downloaded num-traits v0.1.43
  Downloaded clipboard v0.5.0
  Downloaded num-complex v0.4.5
  Downloaded unic-langid-impl v0.8.0
  Downloaded generic-array v0.13.3
  Downloaded derivative v1.0.4
  Downloaded fluent-bundle v0.11.0
  Downloaded crossbeam-utils v0.7.2
  Downloaded stable_deref_trait v1.2.0
  Downloaded rand_chacha v0.1.1
  Downloaded lock_api v0.3.4
  Downloaded unic-langid v0.8.0
  Downloaded inventory v0.1.11
  Downloaded ordered-float v1.1.1
  Downloaded crossbeam-queue v0.1.2
  Downloaded glyph_brush_layout v0.1.9
  Downloaded err-derive v0.2.4
  Downloaded crossbeam-deque v0.7.4
  Downloaded approx v0.3.2
  Downloaded clipboard-win v2.2.0
  Downloaded crossbeam-utils v0.6.6
  Downloaded gif v0.10.3
  Downloaded matrixmultiply v0.2.4
  Downloaded ahash v0.3.8
  Downloaded scoped_threadpool v0.1.9
  Downloaded rusttype v0.8.3
  Downloaded num v0.4.1
  Downloaded humantime v1.3.0
  Downloaded gltf-json v0.15.2
  Downloaded float-ord v0.2.0
  Downloaded paste-impl v0.1.18
  Downloaded unicode-xid v0.1.0
  Downloaded vergen v3.2.0
  Downloaded tynm v0.1.9
  Downloaded failure_derive v0.1.8
  Downloaded ghost v0.1.17
  Downloaded crossbeam-channel v0.3.9
  Downloaded genmesh v0.6.2
  Downloaded proc-macro-error-attr v1.0.4
  Downloaded dunce v1.0.4
  Downloaded linked-hash-map v0.5.6
  Downloaded heck v0.3.3
  Downloaded minterpolate v0.4.0
  Downloaded mopa v0.2.2
  Downloaded dirs-sys v0.3.7
  Downloaded ctor v0.1.26
  Downloaded nodrop v0.1.14
  Downloaded 215 crates (15.7 MB) in 13.46s (largest was `rodio` at 7.1 MB)
   Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.78
   Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.12
   Compiling serde v1.0.196
   Compiling winapi v0.3.9
   Compiling libm v0.2.8
   Compiling syn v1.0.109
   Compiling byteorder v1.5.0
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling cfg-if v0.1.10
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
   Compiling cc v1.0.83
   Compiling maybe-uninit v2.0.0
   Compiling num-traits v0.2.17
   Compiling crossbeam-utils v0.8.19
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
   Compiling num-integer v0.1.45
   Compiling rayon-core v1.12.1
   Compiling quote v1.0.35
   Compiling proc-macro2 v0.4.30
   Compiling either v1.9.0
   Compiling syn v2.0.48
   Compiling crossbeam-epoch v0.9.18
error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::devpropdef`
 --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\shared\devpkey.rs:7:13
  |
7 | use shared::devpropdef::DEVPROPKEY;
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `devpropdef` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::wtypesbase`
 --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\shared\winerror.rs:9:13
  |
9 | use shared::wtypesbase::SCODE;
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `wtypesbase` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::mmreg`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\audioclient.rs:11:13
   |
11 | use shared::mmreg::WAVEFORMATEX;
   |             ^^^^^ could not find `mmreg` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::wtypesbase`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\audioclient.rs:13:13
   |
13 | use shared::wtypesbase::SCODE;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `wtypesbase` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::strmif`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\audioclient.rs:15:9
   |
15 | use um::strmif::REFERENCE_TIME;
   |         ^^^^^^ could not find `strmif` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::rpcdce`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\combaseapi.rs:11:13
   |
11 | use shared::rpcdce::{RPC_AUTHZ_HANDLE, RPC_AUTH_IDENTITY_HANDLE};
   |             ^^^^^^ could not find `rpcdce` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::wtypesbase`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\combaseapi.rs:12:13
   |
12 | use shared::wtypesbase::{
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `wtypesbase` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::objidl`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\combaseapi.rs:16:9
   |
16 | use um::objidl::SOLE_AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE;
   |         ^^^^^^ could not find `objidl` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::objidlbase`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\combaseapi.rs:17:9
   |
17 | use um::objidlbase::{
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `objidlbase` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::propidl`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\combaseapi.rs:21:9
   |
21 | use um::propidl::PROPVARIANT;
   |         ^^^^^^^ could not find `propidl` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::wincontypes`
 --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\consoleapi.rs:9:9
  |
9 | use um::wincontypes::{COORD, HPCON, PINPUT_RECORD};
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `wincontypes` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::windef`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\dwmapi.rs:11:13
   |
11 | use shared::windef::{HBITMAP, HWND, POINT, PSIZE, RECT};
   |             ^^^^^^ could not find `windef` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::uxtheme`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\dwmapi.rs:12:9
   |
12 | use um::uxtheme::MARGINS;
   |         ^^^^^^^ could not find `uxtheme` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::windef`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\dwrite.rs:11:13
   |
11 | use shared::windef::{COLORREF, HDC, HMONITOR, RECT, SIZE};
   |             ^^^^^^ could not find `windef` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::d2d1`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\dwrite.rs:13:9
   |
13 | use um::d2d1::ID2D1SimplifiedGeometrySink;
   |         ^^^^ could not find `d2d1` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::dcommon`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\dwrite.rs:14:9
   |
14 | use um::dcommon::DWRITE_MEASURING_MODE;
   |         ^^^^^^^ could not find `dcommon` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::dcommon`
 --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\dwrite_1.rs:9:9
  |
9 | use um::dcommon::DWRITE_MEASURING_MODE;
  |         ^^^^^^^ could not find `dcommon` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::dcommon`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\dwrite_3.rs:10:9
   |
10 | use um::dcommon::{DWRITE_GLYPH_IMAGE_DATA, DWRITE_GLYPH_IMAGE_FORMATS, DWRITE_MEASURING_MODE};
   |         ^^^^^^^ could not find `dcommon` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::dwrite_2`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\dwrite_3.rs:23:9
   |
23 | use um::dwrite_2::{
   |         ^^^^^^^^ could not find `dwrite_2` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::wtypes`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\mmdeviceapi.rs:11:13
   |
11 | use shared::wtypes::PROPERTYKEY;
   |             ^^^^^^ could not find `wtypes` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::propidl`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\mmdeviceapi.rs:12:9
   |
12 | use um::propidl::PROPVARIANT;
   |         ^^^^^^^ could not find `propidl` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::propsys`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\mmdeviceapi.rs:13:9
   |
13 | use um::propsys::IPropertyStore;
   |         ^^^^^^^ could not find `propsys` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::sspi`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\ntsecapi.rs:11:13
   |
11 | use shared::sspi::SecHandle;
   |             ^^^^ could not find `sspi` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::lsalookup`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\ntsecapi.rs:12:9
   |
12 | use um::lsalookup::{
   |         ^^^^^^^^^ could not find `lsalookup` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::subauth`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\ntsecapi.rs:15:9
   |
15 | use um::subauth::{PUNICODE_STRING, STRING, UNICODE_STRING};
   |         ^^^^^^^ could not find `subauth` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::windef`
 --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\ole2.rs:7:13
  |
7 | use shared::windef::HWND;
  |             ^^^^^^ could not find `windef` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::oleidl`
 --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\ole2.rs:8:9
  |
8 | use um::oleidl::LPDROPTARGET;
  |         ^^^^^^ could not find `oleidl` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::windef`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\shellapi.rs:13:13
   |
13 | use shared::windef::{HICON, HWND, POINT, RECT};
   |             ^^^^^^ could not find `windef` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::windef`
 --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\shellscalingapi.rs:7:13
  |
7 | use shared::windef::HMONITOR;
  |             ^^^^^^ could not find `windef` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::windef`
 --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\shlobj.rs:9:13
  |
9 | use shared::windef::HWND;
  |             ^^^^^^ could not find `windef` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::shtypes`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\shlobj.rs:11:9
   |
11 | use um::shtypes::{PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE, PCUITEMID_CHILD_ARRAY, PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE, REFKNOWNFOLDERID};
   |         ^^^^^^^ could not find `shtypes` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::windef`
 --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\shobjidl_core.rs:9:13
  |
9 | use shared::windef::{COLORREF, HICON, HWND, RECT};
  |             ^^^^^^ could not find `windef` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::commctrl`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\shobjidl_core.rs:10:9
   |
10 | use um::commctrl::HIMAGELIST;
   |         ^^^^^^^^ could not find `commctrl` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::objidl`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\shobjidl_core.rs:12:9
   |
12 | use um::objidl::IBindCtx;
   |         ^^^^^^ could not find `objidl` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::propkeydef`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\shobjidl_core.rs:13:9
   |
13 | use um::propkeydef::REFPROPERTYKEY;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `propkeydef` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::propsys`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\shobjidl_core.rs:14:9
   |
14 | use um::propsys::GETPROPERTYSTOREFLAGS;
   |         ^^^^^^^ could not find `propsys` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::shtypes`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\shobjidl_core.rs:15:9
   |
15 | use um::shtypes::{PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE, PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE};
   |         ^^^^^^^ could not find `shtypes` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::windef`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\winbase.rs:18:13
   |
18 | use shared::windef::HWND;
   |             ^^^^^^ could not find `windef` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::cfgmgr32`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\winbase.rs:19:9
   |
19 | use um::cfgmgr32::MAX_PROFILE_LEN;
   |         ^^^^^^^^ could not find `cfgmgr32` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `vc::vadefs`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\winbase.rs:47:9
   |
47 | use vc::vadefs::va_list;
   |         ^^^^^^ could not find `vadefs` in `vc`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::windef`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\wincon.rs:10:13
   |
10 | use shared::windef::{COLORREF, HWND};
   |             ^^^^^^ could not find `windef` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `um::wincontypes`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\wincon.rs:18:13
   |
18 | pub use um::wincontypes::{
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `wincontypes` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::windef`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\wingdi.rs:13:13
   |
13 | use shared::windef::{
   |             ^^^^^^ could not find `windef` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::ktmtypes`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\winnt.rs:13:13
   |
13 | use shared::ktmtypes::UOW;
   |             ^^^^^^^^ could not find `ktmtypes` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `vc::excpt`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\winnt.rs:17:9
   |
17 | use vc::excpt::EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION;
   |         ^^^^^ could not find `excpt` in `vc`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `vc::vcruntime`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\winnt.rs:18:9
   |
18 | use vc::vcruntime::size_t;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^ could not find `vcruntime` in `vc`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `shared::windef`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\winuser.rs:19:13
   |
19 | use shared::windef::{
   |             ^^^^^^ could not find `windef` in `shared`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `vc::limits`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\winuser.rs:32:9
   |
32 | use vc::limits::UINT_MAX;
   |         ^^^^^^ could not find `limits` in `vc`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `vc::vadefs`
  --> C:\Users\comp\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\um\winuser.rs:33:9
   |
33 | use vc::vadefs::va_list;
   |         ^^^^^^ could not find `vadefs` in `vc`

   Compiling crossbeam-deque v0.8.5
   Compiling backtrace v0.3.69
   Compiling semver-parser v0.7.0
   Compiling unicode-xid v0.1.0
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `winapi` (lib) due to 49 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...

C:\Dima\Rust\amethyst-0.15.1>
```

в сумме в общем не запускаются все 3д движки на  rust (bevy, Fyrox, Piston). Вот не знаю возможно это из нехватки  сдк вулкан (почему-то всё на нём в расте) ?

Comment: `winapi v0.3.9` — дубликат же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1564573

Comment: @andreymal так в чëм ошибка то?

Comment: А я сам ещё не понял. Учитывая, что вы опять пытаетесь использовать что-то очень древнее — может, конфликт каких-нибудь старых версий крейтов друг с другом

Comment: @andreymal у меня есть предположение что проблема в самом расте он пока ещё слишком не отлажен и 3д движки ставятся у 80 процентов из 100 процентов.  я как раз попал в эти 20 процентов. Либо вулкан сдк надо установить я не ставил.

Comment: Тогда бы эти 20 процентов очень активно орали бы в интернете о кривости раста. На деле же мне удалось найти [всего одного](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/issues/803) с хотя бы отдалённо похожей проблемой, да и того завернули с "у меня всё работает"

Comment: @andreymal да врасте аудитория 10 человек , вот как раз у меня и сашки не запустилось :3